# Keep date in pandas groupby rolling aggregation

Tags: pandas, group-by

I'm running the code below for computing rolling statistics over date on a dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
                   'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
                   'value': [5, 4, 7, 2, 7, 1]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(2).agg({'sum': 'sum', 'mean': 'mean'})
```

The code does not keep date in the result. Ideally I would like to keep the date for each statistics over time, but I only get an index number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `date` as index to preserve it during aggregation:

```
out = (df.set_index('date').groupby('id')['value']
       .rolling(2).agg(['sum', 'mean']).reset_index())
print(out)
```

---

```
   id       date   sum  mean
0   1 2023-01-01   NaN   NaN
1   1 2023-01-02   9.0   4.5
2   1 2023-01-03  11.0   5.5
3   2 2023-01-01   NaN   NaN
4   2 2023-01-02   9.0   4.5
5   2 2023-01-03   8.0   4.0
```